# Simplifying hyperbolic compositions like $\sinh (N \operatorname{acosh} a)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, hyperbolic-functions

In many occasions, we may meet hyperbolic functions, as well as their combined ones. I want to simplify expressions like
$$
\tanh\left( N\left(\textrm{acosh}~ a\right)\right)
$$
and
$$
\sinh\left( N\left(\textrm{acosh}~ a\right)\right)
$$
for any positive integer $N$.

---

My WAY:

By the substitution $b=\textrm{acosh}~ a$, then $a=\cosh b$, and we have
$$
\tanh\left( N\left(\textrm{acosh}~ a\right)\right) = \tanh\left( Nb\right)
$$
If $N=1$, then
$$
\tanh\left(\textrm{acosh}~ a\right) = \tanh\left(b\right)=\frac{\sqrt{a^2-1}}{a}
$$
But how to do this for general $N$?

Tks.

EDIT: please see my new [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623561/prove-the-identity-tanhn-textrmacosh-a-vert-fracg2n-1g2n1) for inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll consider the case where the "outer" hyperbolic trigonometric function is $\sinh$, which contains the essential ideas of the general case. The key observation is that for any integer $N$ we can write $\sinh N x$ as some polynomial $P_N(\sinh x)$ in $\sinh x$ (of degree $N$), so that for any function $f(a)$ we have
$$\sinh [N f(a)] = P_N(\sinh f(a)).$$

In the case that $f$ is an inverse trigonometric function, using either explicit computation or a hyperbolic reference triangle, we can write $\sinh f(a)$ as an algebraic expression in $a$, for example, $$\sinh \operatorname{arcosh} a = \sqrt{a^2 - 1} ,$$ and hence $$\sinh (N \operatorname{arcosh} a) = P_N(\sinh \operatorname{arcosh a}) = P_N\left(\sqrt{a^2 - 1}\right) .$$

As an example, we'll work out $P_3$ (again, this contains the essential ideas of the general case) and give an explicitly algebraic formula for $$\sinh (3 \operatorname{arcosh} a).$$

By definition, we have 
\begin{align}
\sinh 3 x
&= \frac{e^{3x} - e^{-3x}}{2}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[(e^x - e^{-x})^3 + 3 (e^x - e^{-x})\right]\\
&= 4 \cdot \left(\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}\right)^3 + 3 \left(\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}\right)\\
&= 4 \sinh^3 x + 3 \sinh x .
\end{align}

Substituting in the above formula we get
$$\sinh (3 \operatorname{arcosh} a) = 4(a^2 - 1)^{3 / 2} + 3(a^2 - 1)^{1 / 2}.$$

One can of course work out general formulas for $P_N$. Likewise, for any integer $N$ there is some polynomial $Q_N$ of degree $N$ such that $\cosh N x = Q_N(\cosh x)$.

Comment: Hi Travis, thank you very much. If you wish, I suggest you to see my new question for fun. The link is presented in the body of the old question.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found my answer useful. I'll check out your new question soon.

Comment: Yes, your answer is useful and quite general. BTW,  I have solved my new question myself, see the link. Thank you for your attention.