# Prove the identity $\tanh(N\textrm{acosh}\;a) = \vert \frac{g^{2N}-1}{g^{2N}+1}\vert$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, hyperbolic-functions

During my recent study, I found an Identity which is of the form
$$
\tanh(N\textrm{acosh}\;a) = \left\vert \frac{g^{2N}-1}{g^{2N}+1}\right\vert
$$
where $a\geq1$ and $g>0$ satisfy $a=\frac{g^2+1}{2g}$. I do not know how to prove it, but my motivation was presented in my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622241/simplifying-hyperbolic-compositions-like-sinh-n-operatornameacosh-a). In the previous question my attempts had been shown.

How about the identity? Could you show me how to prove it?

---

Im Sorry, but I know how to prove it now. The main idea lies in that, if $g=a+\sqrt{a^2-1}$, then
$$
\tanh(N\ln g) = \tanh(N\ln(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})) = \tanh(N\textrm{acosh}\;a)
$$
and by the substitution $x=N\ln g$
$$
\tanh(N\ln g) = \tanh x = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}} = \frac{g^N-g^{-N}}{g^N+g^{-N}}=\frac{g^{2N}-1}{g^{2N}+1}.
$$

Comment: If you wish, you can answer your own question and accept your own answer.